# how to create an optional route parameter for zend framework 2 restful route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working with zend framework 2 and I need to create an optional parameter for a route segment that also has two required parameters.  Below is a snippet from the module.config.php describing the route.  My understanding is that in ZF2 an optional route parameter can be created by using the

```
[/:param]
```

which you can see is what I have.  It works fine as long as I send the optional param, but when I leave it out the first two params "uname and appname" are appended together into the "uname" constraint.  The route is a parent route.

```
'roles' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
              'route' => '/roles/:uname/:appname[/:locnames]',
              'constraints' => array(
                'uname' => '[a-zA-Z].+',
                'appname' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-].+',
                'locnames' => 'locnames'
             ),
             'defaults' => array(
                 'controller' => 'Roles/Controller/RolesController'
              ),
            ),
        ),
```

What am I missing here, I know you can have define optional parameters, but I can't figure out the correct format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to grizzm0 on #zftalk or helping me with this one.  It was a simple regular expressions issue.  Removing the dot(.) in the constraints correctly matched the incoming url parameters.  So my route now looks like this:

```
'roles' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
      'route' => '/roles[/:action][/uname/:uname][/appname/:appname][/locnames/:locnames]',
      'constraints' => array(
        'uname' => '[a-zA-Z]+',
        'appname' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        'locnames' => 'locnames'
     ),
     'defaults' => array(
         'controller' => 'Roles/Controller/RolesController'
      ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'roles' => array(
        'type' => 'segment',
        'options' => array(
          'route' => '/roles[/:action][/uname/:uname][/appname/:appname][/locnames/:locnames]',
          'constraints' => array(
            'uname' => '[a-zA-Z].+',
            'appname' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-].+',
            'locnames' => 'locnames'
         ),
         'defaults' => array(
             'controller' => 'Roles/Controller/RolesController'
          ),
        ),
    ),
```

You can configure your route like this way.
Here inside your roles controller 
you have some action live index.
so your route will be 
siteurl/roles/index/uname/john/appname/stackexchange/locanames/yourlocanames

here if you don't want to write appname then remove youre paramater so your route will work.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but configuring the route as you suggested didn't work.  The controller couldn't be matched by the router.  I forgot to mention that my controller extends AbstractRestfulController.  I simply want a rest url like /roles/uname/appname/[locnames]   Maybe the AbstractRestfulController does not allow optional parameters in the route